Conditions succeeded() and failed() seem to indicate success even when failed
I'm running a lot of unit tests, using VSTest@2, and all is good - a failed test is shown as a failed test.
All the test results have to be logged into a Markdown file in a specific format, which seemed simple - the conditions succeeded() and failed() should do the job. But, although failed tests are clearly shown in the DevOps UI as failed, they are shown as succeeded in the code below.
Does anyone have an idea where my problem might be? Could it be because continueOnError is mostly set to true? DevOps still knows the test has failed.
    - ${{ each test in parameters.unitTestsList }}:
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'Test ${{ test.name }}'
        continueOnError: ${{ parameters.continueOnError }}
        timeoutInMinutes: 45
        inputs:
          vsTestVersion: $(vsTestVersion)
          testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\${{ test.file }}      
          testRunTitle: ${{ test.name }}
          searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\${{ parameters.productName }}'
          runInParallel: ${{ test.parallel }}
          runTestsInIsolation: false
          codeCoverageEnabled: true
          configuration: ${{ parameters.configuration }}
          platform: $(buildPlatform)
          diagnosticsEnabled: true 
           
      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: succeeded()
        displayName: 'Logging success'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Add-Content -Path $(buildLogFile) ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "Success: ${{ test.name }}  ")
    
      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: failed()
        displayName: 'Logging FAILURE'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Add-Content -Path $(buildLogFile) ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "FAILED: ${{ test.name }}  ")


By although failed tests are clearly shown in the DevOps UI as failed, they are shown as succeeded you mean the Logging success task is always being run?

What happens if you remove the continueOnError property from the VSTest@2 task and set the condition to always()?

Yes, the "Logging success" task is always run.
The tests run for over 10 hours, and we would like to know which tests failed, instead of stopping at the first failure (that might happen after 8 hours), hence the continueOnError

Have you considered running a separate job for each test assembly instead of a task? This way you can run the jobs in parallel, and it might be easier to identify which tests are failing - at least the failing assemblies.

Running separate jobs is, for various reasons, not an option.
With DevOps system diagnostics enabled, I get, for a failed (!) unit test:
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: '     Logging success' ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded() ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded: ##[debug]=> True ##[debug]Result: True If the step just above this step fails, I would expect succeeded()` to be false!?

According to Pipeline conditions,

Only when a previous dependency fails. Use failed() in the YAML for this condition.


By default, stages, jobs, and steps run if all direct and indirect dependencies succeed. This status is the same as specifying condition: succeeded().

When you set continueOnError to true in VSTest@2 task, the state of the task will be partiallySucceeded if there are failed tests. "partiallySucceeded" is considered to be successful, so "Logging success" will continue to run, and "Logging FAILURE" will be skipped.

Workaround:
As a workaround, we can Run REST API Timeline - Get to get the timeline of the build and check the result of the VSTest@2 task. Then output the corresponding tests.
For example,
- ${{ each test in parameters.tests }}:
  - task: VSTest@2
    condition: always()
    displayName: Run-${{test}}
    inputs:
      vsTestVersion: $(vsTestVersion)
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\${{ test.file }}      
      ...
      

  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: always()
    displayName: 'Output the failed/passed tests'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $taskName = "Run-${{test}}"
        $head = @{
          'Authorization' = "bearer " + "$(System.AccessToken)"
                  }
        $url1 ="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=6.0"
        $timeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method Get -Headers $head
        $task = $timeline.records | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $taskName} | Select-Object 
        Write-Host $task.result
        if ($task.result -eq "succeeded") {
            Add-Content -Path $(buildLogFile) ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "Success: ${{ test.name }}  ")
        } elseif ($task.result -eq "failed") {
            Add-Content -Path $(buildLogFile) ("{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "FAILED: ${{ test.name }}  ")
        }


Remove continueOnError from task VSTest@2 and add condition: always(). So that this task will run even if previous tests failed.

The displayName of the VSTest@2 task must contain your parameter. It's Run-${{test}} in my example. We need to use it to locate the corresponding task in the API response in the next PowerShell task.

In PowerShell@2 task, add condition: always().

Call REST API Timeline - Get to get the timeline of the current build and check the result of the VSTest@2 task in this loop. Ensure to replace { } in the scripts with your actual value.


Result:


that looks great, thank you!  I should have mentioned that we are using DevOps Server, and the Timeline Get seems to be for cloud-based DevOps. Is there a way to get your approach working on local DevOps?

Just change the request URL to https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=7.0. See more details from this doc. Please note that in the actual request url, there isn't a specific timeline. We need to get all the timeline of one build, which is a little different from the doc.

It works! Fabulous, thank you very much indeed!
I guess the same approach would work for other tasks, like builds, as well?

I think so. The idea is the same, use parameter to bind task, and then use it to filter target information from timeline.

Your suggestion works just great! It brought another small problem - the "failed" status seems to stay, so anything (and there are many steps in my workflow needs a condition: always(), and continueOnError doesn't work when an error during unit tests is still remembered. Is there any way to clear that 'failed' flag that must be stored somewhere?

You can try to set continueOnError to true in VSTest@2 task and change the condition elseif ($task.result -eq "failed") to elseif ($task.result -eq "succeededWithIssues").

That works perfectly well. Excellent, problem solved, thank you very much indeed!
